# Serve a Bottle application from gunicorn on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, bottle, gunicorn, procfile

#### Procfile

```
web: python server.py
```

#### server.py

```py
from os import environ
from bottle import app, route, run, static_file

@route('/')
def root():
    return "Hello world!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(server='gunicorn', host='0.0.0.0', port=int(environ.get("PORT", 5000)))
```

#### requirements.txt

```
gunicorn
psycopg2
git+https://github.com/defnull/bottle#egg=bottle
```

---

#### Relevant portion of logfile (after `git push`)

> heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: Are you certain that those are *all* of the necessary requirements?

If they are, are you sure you have any dynos allocated? What's the result of `heroku ps`? H14 is listed as usually being caused by having no dynos set to run your app.

You can set it to use one web dyno with `heroku ps:scale web=1`.

Comment: I was previously running web2py through gunicorn on this app. I have just deleted all those files and replaced it with the aforementioned files. `heroku ps` shows me nothing. `heroku run python server.py` works, hosting it on a random port (and attaching it to my console).

Comment: Try `heroku ps:scale web=1` and the problem may resolve itself.

Comment: That's odd, thanks; that last command worked. Edit your answer and I'll upvote it also :)

Comment: The last command is the fix for the problem I suggested you might have in the question. Do you know how Heroku works?