# Bottle app on heroku with gunicorn - foreman works locally but not on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, bottle, gunicorn

I've been stuck trying to get my simple `bottle` app starting when deployed on heroku.

After quite some searching and tinkering I've got a setup that works locally, but not on heroku.

In `/app.py`:

```
import bottle
import beaker.middleware
from bottle import route, redirect, post, run, request, hook, template, static_file, default_app

bottle.debug(True)
app = beaker.middleware.SessionMiddleware(bottle.app(), session_opts)
...
# app routes etc, no run()
```

Then in `/Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn app:app --bind="0.0.0.0:$PORT" --debug
```

Correct me if I misunderstand how gunicorn works, I understand the "app:app" portion as look in the module (=file) called app.py and use whatever is in variable "app" as your WSIG, yes?

- I've checked via `$ heroku run bash` if $PORT is set, seems ok
- The "0.0.0.0" IP I've got from other heroku examples, that should anyway accept any IPs server end, no?
- Python dependencies seem to get installed fine
- I've got this locally running by setting the `$POST` variable via an `.env` file for foreman, everything seems working ok on my setup
- Based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556082/serve-a-bottle-application-from-gunicorn-on-heroku) I checked `$ heroku ps`

`` === web (1X): `gunicorn app:app --bind="0.0.0.0:$PORT" --debug` 
web.1: crashed 2014/12/24 22:43:00 (~ 1m ago)*) ``

- And `$ heroku logs` shows:

`` 2014-12-24T20:42:59.235657+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app --bind="0.0.0.0:23177" --debug`
2014-12-24T20:43:00.434570+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-12-24T20:43:01.813679+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2014-12-24T20:43:01.803122+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3 ``

Not sure really how I could get better debugging results either. Somehow the `Procfile` web process just doesn't seem to work / start, but how can I get info on what's breaking?

Anybody got ideas what's going on here?

*P.S.: I'm rather new to heroku, python, bottle & gunicorn :O*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of gunicorn do you use?
gunicorn 19.1 doesn't write errorlog by default.  Try `gunicorn --log-file=-`.

`-R` is also useful option to investigate error.

Comment: Thanks, tried, even though I couldn't find an option `--log-file`, but maybe `--access-logfile="-"` does the same? Result still the same, locally works, on heroku the app crashes.

Comment: No. --access-logfile is accesslog.  --log-file is errorlog.
http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#errorlog

Comment: Ahhh, that did it. Got error traces and apparently I had one module on .gitignore by mistake (but present locally), which made the whole thing crash and burn on heroku. Also I didn't see the command alias when I checked the documentation, so thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try having just `web: gunicorn app:app` in your Procfile with nothing else?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried it and it doesn't work on heroku, but locally. As expected, I might add, because heroku, to my understanding, dynamically provides the port that the app should listen on.

Comment: @kontur Interestingly, I'm currently running a flask app on heroku, which works with just that in the Procfile...

Comment: Hm, maybe your app module somehow retrieves the port number when it starts? Thanks for the suggestion though, unfortunately it doesn't seem to do the trick for this problem.